# Cisco ASA5585-X replace SSP-20 with SSP-60

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, network

We have cisco `ASA5585-X` with SSP-20 running in production and we need more power so planning to replace SSP-20 with SSP-60 module but not sure we can just hot swap with SSP-20?

Does ASA5585-X support two different version of SSP running on single chassis? if yes then i can replace them one by one. I didn't find any official doc claim that so asking you folks if you have any experience related this scenario

Comment: One thing I have learned over the years is to never, and I mean never, depend on no outage when adding, removing, or replacing anything in a network device, regardless of vendor or what the vendor claims. There are simply too many things that can and will go wrong.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this document **Cisco ASA 5585-X Hardware Installation Guide** https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/hw/maintenance/5585guide/5585Xhw/overview.html dated December 14 2017:

> Note Online insertion and removal (OIR) of SSPs and network modules is
>   not supported at this time. Small form-factor pluggable (SFP/SFP+)
>   transceiver, power-supply module, and fan module OIR is supported.

I also would not expect different SSP modules to work, and odds are a reboot would be required to initialize the data structures, but that's just me guessing, not based on documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but i heard when you put both SSP on single chassis they act like individual module and no interaction with other SSP in that case why this method not supported?

Comment: fyi, whatever link you posted is broken.

Comment: @Satish corrected and tested. Thanks!

Comment: @Satish that’s a question for the vendor, but ASA  always emphasized “chassis redundancy” (in other words “buying two for double the price”).  Supporting mismatched SSPs while hot swapping hardware is a horrific corner case that has very few customers and large testing requirements, so why allocate development resources?